# How to get .apk files details (like: name, id, vercode ..etc) stored in external storage of android device

Tags: java, android, file, apk

How can I get the **.apk files** details(like: name, package-name, vercode ..etc) stored in directory(like: /storage/emulated/0/downloads) even if they are **not installed** on the device.

for instance, **1mobile market** can get **all .apk files** stored in your device and ask you to install them.

As showing in the screen shot, those apps not installed on my device and yet the the **Market** can load the icon, name, version and size. HOW?!

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the details of the apk file using package manager:

just check following documentation link: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
 public PackageInfo getPackageArchiveInfo (String archiveFilePath, int flags)
```

Comment: accurate and short answer, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually apk files are `zip archives`, you can rename the file to `yourAppName.apk.zip` and extract it with any zip utility (e.g. 7zip).

The `androidmanifest.xml` file and the resources will be extracted and ther you will find all this info...

**NOTE**: *the source code is not in the package - just the compiled .dex file ("Dalvik Executable")*

Answer (score 0):

An apk file is really just a **zip archive** with a different name. Rename `x.apk` to `x.zip`, where x is the name of the file, and you will be able to open it with any zip tool. It really depends on what information you're after as to whether you can find it in the apk file. I can say that you can access the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in which key information about the access rights of the app etc is stored in a fairly readable form.

Comment: The `AndroidManifest.xml` is compressed/encrypted and not in readable form as you said

Answer (score 0):

You can use "aapt dump badging " and it will give you application details

```
                   Process p;
                    try {
                        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(aapt dump badging <APK_FILE NAME>);
                        p.waitFor();
                        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        String line = "";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            output.append(line);
                            break;
                        }
                        logger.info("Output : " + output);
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final String[] outputSplit = output.toString().split("'");
                    for (int i = 0; i < outputSplit.length; i++) {
                        switch (i) {
                        case 1:
                            packagename = outputSplit[i];
                            logger.info("Package : " + packagename);
                        break;
                        case 3:
                            mversionId = outputSplit[i];
                            logger.info("Version Code : " + mversionId);
                        break;
                        case 5:
                            versionId = outputSplit[i];
                            logger.info("Version Name : " + versionId);
                        break;
                        }
                    }
```

Hop it will work.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply parsing google play store page details.